# Implementing Satellite Menu for Android, XML File States No Resource Found

Tags: android

First off, I'm attempting to use this library and I'm trying to get a base test program to compile: https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

I've saved the project to my hard drive and imported it into Eclipse. I've also made sure it's compiling with Java 1.6 and is set to 'is library'. The actual library is set within Eclipse without any errors.

As for my project, I've followed the instructions listed on GitHub, but I'm getting these errors from my XML file:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'satelliteDistance' in package 'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'mainImage' in package 'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'closeOnClick' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'expandDuration' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'totalSpacingDegree' in package 'android.view.ext'
```

Here's the entire XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.view.ext"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" 
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
    sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    sat:totalSpacingDegree="90"
    sat:closeOnClick="true"
    sat:expandDuration="500"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And my Java source file:

```
package com.example.test_satellite_menu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu;
import android.view.ext.SatelliteMenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SatelliteMenu menu = (SatelliteMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<SatelliteMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<SatelliteMenuItem>();
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(3, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(2, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(1, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I've made sure that my test project has the satellite menu library included with it, and I've used 'fix project properties' as well as 'clean project', so now I'm out of ideas :) Any feedback on getting this to work would be awesome. Thanks!

---

Found my own answer after some more reading through StackOverflow. Had to change the android.view.awt package name to the package name of my current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my own answer after some more reading through StackOverflow. Had to change the android.view.awt package name to the package name of my current project.

Comment: hey i am getting some problem in this example could you plz explain the steps to implement satellite menu ..... thanks

Comment: If you can explain the steps that would help others too .

Comment: I did explain the steps... you change the package name (listed in the XML file) to match your package name...

Comment: I have added satellite menu by changing package in my xml. I have changed it from android.view.awt to com.myapp.activity.Now errors are gone it is satellite menu is showing in graphical layout also but not showing when run on device.Please advise

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.activities"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    >

    <com.example.android.activities.SatelliteMenu
        android:id="@+id/satteliteMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        sat:closeOnClick="false"
        sat:expandDuration="500"
        sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        sat:satelliteDistance="130dp"
        sat:totalSpacingDegree="180" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Edit xmlns and add your project package name after /res/..
and clear your project.

Comment: You're about a year and a half late :)

Comment: @PaulRuiz Better late than never.

Answer (score 0):

```
     SatelliteMenu menu = (SatelliteMenu) findViewById(R.id.satelliteMenu1);
     float distance = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,            170, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
              menu.setSatelliteDistance((int) distance);
              menu.setExpandDuration(300);
              menu.setCloseItemsOnClick(true);
              menu.setTotalSpacingDegree(120);

    List<SatelliteMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<SatelliteMenuItem>();
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(6, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(5, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(3, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(2, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(1, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    menu.addItems(items);
```