# Setting up a satellite menu in my project

Tags: android

I've been pointed towards this project here:

https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

On downloading it looks to be great. But I can't get a simple version working in my application. I have added the .jar provided to my project and it's appearing in the dependancys. The problem I'm having is with the xml file. It is provided like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.view.ext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" 
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
        sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        sat:totalSpacingDegree="90"
        sat:closeOnClick="true"
        sat:expandDuration="500"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Another post on SO says to change the package type to your own package. So I've changed it to:

```
xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.app"
```

But I'm still getting this error in the xml file:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'satelliteDistance' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'mainImage' in package 'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'closeOnClick' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'expandDuration' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'totalSpacingDegree' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
```

I've tried changing the package deceleration here also:

```
<android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu"
```

And combinations of one and the other. But I just keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.view.ext
```

to

```
xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This should work, worked for me though.

Don't forget to clean your project.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similiar question here, [Implementing Satellite Menu for Android, XML File States No Resource Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679134/implementing-satellite-menu-for-android-xml-file-states-no-resource-found)

So you just need to change the package name `android.view.ext`  to your own package name like `com.tac.grewords`, clean the project and everything should be ok now.

Comment: It fixed the compile time error..but when I run it force closes

Answer (score 0):

```
SatelliteMenu menu = (SatelliteMenu) findViewById(R.id.satelliteMenu1);
    float distance = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 170, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //The distance of items from the center button
    menu.setSatelliteDistance((int) distance);
    //The duration of expand and collapse operations in milliseconds.
    menu.setExpandDuration(300);
    menu.setCloseItemsOnClick(true);
    //The degree between the first and the last item.
    menu.setTotalSpacingDegree(120);

    List<SatelliteMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<SatelliteMenuItem>();
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(6, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(5, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(3, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(2, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(1, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    menu.addItems(items);
```

add satellite menu as library from project properties. Then you will get satellite menu in custom and library view just drag and drop it in your xml file. Then put above code in your java file which actually set data for satellite menu.