# Implementing Satellite Menu for Android (InflateException: Binary XML file line #9)

Tags: android, android-menu

i'm try to implement Satellite Menu for Android and receive this error on locat :

Android android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.example.uploadvideo.SatelliteMenu

i added in my java file these lines  :

```
    SatelliteMenu menu = (SatelliteMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu);

//        Set from XML, possible to programmatically set        
//        float distance = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 170, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
//        menu.setSatelliteDistance((int) distance);
//        menu.setExpandDuration(500);
//        menu.setCloseItemsOnClick(false);
//        menu.setTotalSpacingDegree(60);

        List<SatelliteMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<SatelliteMenuItem>();
        items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_1));
        items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_3));
        items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_4));
        items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(3, R.drawable.ic_5));
        items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(2, R.drawable.ic_6));
        items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(1, R.drawable.ic_2));
//        items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(5, R.drawable.sat_item));
        menu.addItems(items);        

        menu.setOnItemClickedListener(new SateliteClickedListener() {

            public void eventOccured(int id) {
                Log.i("sat", "Clicked on " + id);
            }
        });
```

and in layout these line :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.uploadvideo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.uploadvideo.SatelliteMenu  <!-- here the problem line 9 -->
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" 
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
        sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        sat:totalSpacingDegree="90"
        sat:closeOnClick="true"
        sat:expandDuration="500"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

[I changed packege name like mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679134/implementing-satellite-menu-for-android-xml-file-states-no-resource-found)

what it could be???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have included the satellite menu project(it is library project) in eclipse, then you need to use the package name specified in the library project. And if you want to change the package name then you have to copy src and res folder of the library project into your project and rename accordingly.
I would suggest you to use as is(i.e. like a library project).

Comment: solotuion : this line "com.example.uploadvideo.SatelliteMenu" need to be "android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu" because of library project , and need to clean the project.  thank you ....